# GolangでXMLの配列をパースしたい

Tags: go, xml

下記のリンクのようなXMLをパースしたく下記の通り実装しましたが、`tags`ないの文字列をうまくパースできません。
できればTagsという文字列の配列にパースしたいのですが可能でしょうか。
innerXMLを使えば、tag構造を文字列として取得できますが、できればその中身の文字列だけ取り出したいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

https://ext.nicovideo.jp/api/getthumbinfo/sm35048506

**実装**

```
package nicoappi

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

// VideoInfo is video information of niconico
type VideoInfo struct {
    Thumb Thumb `xml:"thumb"`
}

// Thumb is inner object of VideoInfo
type Thumb struct {
    VideoID      string `xml:"video_id"`
    Title        string `xml:"title"`
    Description  string `xml:"description"`
    Tags         []string  `xml:"tags"`
    UserNickname string `xml:"user_nickname"`
}

// Tag is a tag
type Tag struct {
    Content string `xml:",chardata"`
}

const baseURL = "https://ext.nicovideo.jp/api/getthumbinfo/"

// GetVideoInfo returns video information
func GetVideoInfo(videoID string) (*VideoInfo, error) {
    res, err := http.Get(baseURL + videoID)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    reader := xml.NewDecoder(res.Body)
    var info VideoInfo
    err = reader.Decode(&info)
    fmt.Println(info.Thumb.Tags)
    return &info, err
}
```

Comment: `Tags []string  \`xml:"tags"\`` を `Tags []string \`xml:"tags>tag"\`` とします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。できました!